# Transfer app and data from iphone 5s to iphone 6s

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 5s (iOS 8.2) and an iPhone 6s (iOS 10.2). On the old iPhone I have a banking app which I'd like to copy securely to the new iPhone, including all the app's data. I do not want to make a full backup. Both devices are using the same credentials for iCloud, none of the devices is jailbroken.

The app does not use iCloud.

Is it possible to copy only this single app without using third party software?

Comment: It may be helpful to state which bank app you are using - I know some of mine behave differently when being set up on a new device. Some need to be re authenticated with the bank, even after a direct restore of a previous iTunes backup.

Answer (score 1):

Given the way online banking is designed you shouldn't need to copy local data for the app, as the app is usually just a client for their website. You should be able to simply download a fresh copy of the app on your newer iPhone, sign in to the app, and load all of the necessary data from their servers (recent deposits/withdrawls/transfers, share account info etc. would all be kept on their end and simply sent to your phone temporarily over the network when the app requested it, unless that is your bank uses a very unorthodox device-locked system, which seems both unlikely as well as unreasonable behaviour for a bank.).

Answer (score 0):

If the app uses iCloud to backup/use its data and the 10.2 version of the app can read the data from the 8.2 version (you can contact the app developer to verify), then you should be able to just download the banking app and use the old data.

For example, I've used many apps on my iPhone's on versions all the way back to iOS6.  With each new iPhone I setup as 'new', the apps that are designed to use the iCloud data simply work.  Of course, I have to make sure I perform a backup of that specific app's data to iCloud before I upgrade, and you'll want to do that too.

I'm very happy with how many well-written apps are using iCloud.  I know that many other people don't have the same experience.  It looks like you're able to use both iPhones at the same time so you should be able to test and make sure your data looks good on the new one before making the permanent switch.

Comment: No it doesn't use iCloud unfortunately. Sorry for not including that information in the question.

Comment: Then I think it will be more difficult, especially if you don't want to use 3rd-party software, like iExplore.  Most popular bank/banking apps have built-in ways to store a copy of their data or a backup.  Check with the developer and see.  If they don't have iCloud integration the app might not work properly on iOS10, either.